# MAMP don't start after update

Tags: macos, mamp

I update MAMP on my Mac to the version 4.5, and after the update, it's impossible to start MAMP.
When I click on the icon, MAMP start and close instantly.

Can you help me please ? Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've got a solution!

Debugging I've notice that: only the MAMP 4.5 Package is damaged. All the files (Apache, MySql, PHP, ecc...) are working fine.

In order to solve this issue I moved the previous MAMP 3.5 Package inside the new folder replacing the new .pkg version, all the references works fine because they point to /Applications/MAMP.

For now it's a workaround which allow to me to continue to do my job.

Answer (score 0):

I updated MAMP from 3.5 to 4.5 one hour ago and I have the same problem as you on OSX Sierra 10.12.

The updating procedure was ended fine but when i try to start MAMP i get this error on system.log:

(de.appsolute.MAMP.23312[1435]): Service exited with abnormal code: 1

Answer (score 0):

So, I contact the support and I've got an answer. The Spanish and French version of MAMP 4.5 are not working, but a clean version arrive the next week.
To download MAMP 4.4.1, here is a link : 
[MAMP 4.4.1](https://www.dropbox.com/sh/9npdp36k0ies0a5/AAC-FL-EeBSfajo0_E7xQ6-sa?dl=0)